# PUT requests to upload a file in form data Using karate

Tags: karate

I've tried to write equivalent karate script for below curl request

```
curl -X PUT \
  'http://localhost:8055/uploadfile' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data;' \
  -F code=@/Users/test/Downloads/Next.zip
```

Tried karate script

```
Given path 'uploadfile'
   #Given header Content-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
   And form field code = '/Users/test/Downloads/Next.zip'
   #And multipart file code =  { read: '/Users/test/Downloads/Next.zip' , contentType: 'application/zip' }
   When method PUT
   Then status 200
```

Am I doing something mistake here (tried different things)? Still not getting expected API response.

FYI : I've got that curl command from postman and it is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell with the limited info you have provided. Try this:

```
Given url 'http://localhost:8055/uploadfile'
And multipart file code = { read: 'file:/Users/test/Downloads/Next.zip', filename: 'Next.zip', contentType: 'application/zip' }
When method put
```

If you are still stuck follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue (or use postman ;)